# Разве может chatgpt служить аудитом?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, очередь-проверок, аудит, генеративный-ии

В запоздалых ответах попался очень развёрнутый и понятный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/886825). Перед ним была плашка "система заподозрила в этом сообщении спам, проверьте его особенно внимательно!". Я проверил особенно внимательно. Сначала принял это за спам, но потом понял, что это не так, вопрос тоже про [wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress).

Нажал <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd> и получил радостное сообщение о том, что это был аудит, и я его провалил. Почему провалил? Потому что это сообщение "очень низкого качества"! Вот скриншот сообщения для простых смертных (в очереди оценка поста кстати была 0):

[image: скрин ответа]

Когда мне сообщили, что я <s>идиот, но может быть вылечюсь</s> что я совершил ошибку в проверке, я увидел комментарий под вопросом, что это gpt:

[image: комментарий под вопросом]

В данном случае я этого сходу не понял, да и вообще эти gpt-посты выглядят нормально, но могут в себе таить ошибки. **Разве может chatGPT служить аудитом?** Бывает же, что посты такие выглядят красиво, а иногда ещё и верны. В таких случаях нужно залезть в профиль участника и посмотреть, как часто он ответы публикует. Но у этого товарища репутация 300+, а у "героев" редко терпения хватает, чтобы больше 200 набрать, поэтому в профиль не заглядывал.

Comment: А как вставлена картинка "Выглядит нормально"? Это ж явно какой-то трюк с форматированием) А то здесь править нельзя, я в "исходниках" посмотреть не могу.

Comment: @Глеб с помощью html-тега `<kbd>`: `<kbd>Выглядит нормально/<kbd>`. Это тег для красивого оформления названий клавиш с клавиатуры и элементов пользовательского интерфейса. Лучше один раз увидеть, чем 100 раз услышать, поэтому вот вам  [ссылка на песочницу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: @Глеб это же просто - жмёте [edit], смотрите как, потом жмёте отмену.

Comment: @aepot на мете нельзя даже этого сделать, пока нет 2к.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь достаточно нетипичный кейз. Сообщение было удалено мной ранее как одно из массовых GPT-ответов, данных этим автором. Отрицательный голос поставлен не мной.

Ответ действительно выглядит нормально, если не вникать в контекст активности автора данного ответа. Система аудита выбирает сообщения автоматически, и давать в очереди проверок такие сообщения на аудит - достаточно коварно с точки зрения сложности их оценки.

Ничего страшного в том, что вы провалили аудит однажды, он был реально сложный. Никаких ограничений на взаимодействие с очередями проверок на вас наложено из-за этого не будет.

К сожалению, полностью исключить такие сообщения из аудита мы не сможем, поэтому будьте внимательны в будущем. Так как GPT-ответы подвергаются модерации, совершенно логично, что они будут периодически всплывать в очередях проверок как при аудите, так и при нормальной обработке очереди.

Comment: Ещё можете пожалуйста перевод поправить?

Comment: @Зонтик вы же не в первый раз. 1) один вопрос - один ответ 2) текст картинкой - неприлично. Оформите пожалуйста другой вопрос про перевод

Comment: Оформил [отдельным вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13098/532877) и [предложил перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13099/532877).