# Нет перевода при провале аудита в "Запоздалых ответах"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, аудит

Перевода нет частично, в случае если, по мнению системы, ответ очень низкокачественный. Замечено в очереди "Заподалые ответы", хотя может, в "Сообщениях низкого качества" тоже перевода нет, одна ли это строка, я не знаю.

Скриншот:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл строку в traducir и предложил перевод: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16756

Ждём утверждения.

Comment: Исправил post = сообщение. Утвердил перевод.